# When do 10 points lie on a cubic? (a la Pascal)

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Pascal theorem gives a necessary and sufficient condition for 6 points to lie on a quadratic curve in terms of lines: $A_1,\ldots,A_6$ lie on a quadric iff 3 intersection points $A_1A_2\cap A_4A_5$, $A_2A_3\cap A_5A_6$, $A_3A_4\cap A_6A_1$ are collinear.

Is there a theorem of this kind for cubic curves: a necessary and sufficient condition for 10 points of a plane to lie on a cubic curve, formulated in terms of conics and lines?

Comment: [The Cayley–Bacharach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Bacharach_theorem) gives a proof of Pascal's theorem. Perhaps [this paper](https://www.msri.org/~de/papers/pdfs/1996-001.pdf) can be of use?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Definitely looks relevant — thank you.

Comment: If it does not bother you, please, I would like you to explain something more about your drawing. How it differs, for example, from the desired ten points of your problem in the following example:
"The cubic $ y = (x-1) (x-5) (x-9) $ has ten points in the two circles $ (x-4) ^ 2 + y ^ 2 = 36 $ and $ (x-6) ^ 2 + (x-22)^2 = 49$"

Comment: Grigory, why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @Quasicoherent Well, my answer was somewhat hasty: the claim that the first thm implies the second uses the 'facts' 2×4=6, 3×4=10 and 2+3=4, I'm afraid. I'll try to post an updated version later.

Comment: …Or maybe someone else will be able to explain the construction in [this presentation](https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/traves/presentations/CAAC2015.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(After Jan-Magnus Økland's comment — thanks again! — I've been able to find an answer.)

**Theorem** ([1], thm CB4). Let $X_1$, $X_2$ be plane curves of degrees $d$ and $e$ respectively, meeting in a collection of $d\cdot e$ distinct points $\Gamma$. If $C$ is any plane curve of degree $d+e-3$ containing all but one point of $\Gamma$, then $C$ contains all of $\Gamma$.

For $d=e=3$ ($d+e-3=3$) this is Chasles's theorem, which implies Pascal theorem.

And $d=e=4$ ($d+e-3=5$) implies the following recipe.

**Theorem** (Traves, Welhau; [2]). Split 10 points into two groups of 5, giving red and blue degree 4 curves (consisting of two conics each) and find intersections of red and blue curves. Our 10 points lie on a cubic iff 6 auxiliary points lie on a conic.

[image: example]

// Caveat. If you'll try to use this recipe in, say, Geogebra you'll see that auxiliary conics frequently don't have enough *real* intersection points.

- [1]: D. Eisenbud, M. Green and J. Harris. [Cayley–Bacharach theorems and conjectures](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1996-33-03/S0273-0979-96-00666-0/S0273-0979-96-00666-0.pdf)// Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 33 (1996), 295–324
- [2]: W. Traves. [Ten Points on a Cubic](https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/traves/presentations/CAAC2015.pdf) (presentation).